# Sync SharePoint list to Outlook as read only

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, outlook, office-integration

I have a SharePoint calendar that I would like for people to be able to sync to their Outlook app for reference, but I want them to sync it as read-only. Reason being is that there are other fields that I need them to fill in when they add events and those fields are not available in Outlook. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Connect to Outlook feature is per user and not per Outlook Client, we can switch to a user with only contribute permission for the calendar list, and then connect this calendar to Outlook, therefore the calendar list in Outlook Client is just read-only.